# How to use "Everything" (Desktop search) SDK in a MFC Application?

Tags: c++, command-line, mfc

I need to use [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) from our MFC application? But, I have not done sth similar before? therefore I need expert help about this topic. Thanks in advance.

- How can I use SDK from C++ MFC application?
- It has a complex example but I need to find out that is anybody using SDK?

Sample code would be appreciated (:

Ok, now I am trying to use Everything SDK but I got below link errors:

```
1>search_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __stdcall Everything_GetResultFileNameA(int)" (__imp_?Everything_GetResultFileNameA@@YGPBDH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>search_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __stdcall Everything_GetResultPathA(int)" (__imp_?Everything_GetResultPathA@@YGPBDH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>search_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall Everything_GetNumResults(void)" (__imp_?Everything_GetNumResults@@YGHXZ) referenced in function _main
1>search_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) int __stdcall Everything_QueryA(int)" (__imp_?Everything_QueryA@@YGHH@Z) referenced in function _main
1>search_test.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __stdcall Everything_SetSearchA(char const *)" (__imp_?Everything_SetSearchA@@YGXPBD@Z) referenced in function _main
1>D:\VS2010\search_test\Debug\search_test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 5 unresolved externals
```

I have rebuilt Everything.lib, checked def file eveything seems correct but then How can I get these link errors? btw I am working on MS VS 2010.

Comment: You should be looking at the "Everything SDK". "command line" is your idea of a solution. That's probably a case of an "XY problem". Your real problem isn't in doing something from the command line, but from MFC/C++

Comment: @MSalters You are right, I am editing question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the 'Everything' SDK you are refering to.
However it seems that you have forgotton to include the library against which to link with.
You should have at least one .lib file as part of the SDK.
Make sure you are linking against it.
Project Settings->Linker->input->additional dependencies

Let me know if you need a more detailed explanation.